# Power On/Off GPRS on windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, gprs

i'm looking for a way to power on or off the GPRS adapter programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx), the ability is already there in the API, as you can see in [this blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/12/23/SDF23ControllingRadioPower.aspx) (the blog is for WiFi but the phone radio and bluetooth work the same way).

THe other option is to call ChangeRadioState in ossvcs.dll yourself (that's what the SDF is doing).