# Power Off GPRS on windows mobile 6.1

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, gprs

I'd like to turn off GPRS connection when I close my aplication.
I looked for other problems but:

[Power On/Off GPRS on windows mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164057/power-on-off-gprs-on-windows-mobile)
When I use OpenNetCF and set radio.RadioState = RadioState.Off; for PhoneRadio I disable all phone module (I could turn off and on but after that user have to type PIN again)

Other solution:
[Closing GPRS Connections On Windows Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705774/closing-gprs-connections-on-windows-mobile)
recommend to use RAS which is deprecated in WinMo and there is no good documentation.

Is there any posibility to turn off GPRS connection in other way (and if its;s possible using managed C# not P/Invoke and winAPI)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You want to close the connection or turn off the radio?  These are two completely separate things.

Comment: I want to close connection, not turn off radio.

Answer (score 2):

Your application is not responsible for closing the connection, just as it's not responsible for opening it.  Under WinMo, the piece that is responsible for connection is the [Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457258.aspx) (CM) and, generally speaking, all requests for connection actions goes through it.  For example, when you open something like an HttpWebRequest, CM is notified and it opens a connection for you.  Closing a connection, is also out of your app's purview.  You can tell CM that you no longer require a connection, but CM is looking for all apps, so it's not going to just shut the connection down.  It's going to keep it alive for some period in the event it is either in use or might be called by other application.

This is just how it is.  You can't end-run around it with one exception.  As the answer you link to says, you can use RAS to forcibly close the connection, but it's not something that I'd recommend becasue it can make CM angry and leave things in a indeterminate state.

Comment: is there any wrapper for Connection Manager in OpenNetCF or some example how to do this?

Comment: Yes, the SDF has a ConnectionManager class.